# Disable certain E-Mail to registered User

Tags: wordpress

I would love to disable that an email is sent to a registered user, when the admin changes that users email address. Reason is, the backend is mainly used as a directory, not as a community plattform.

I haven't found the spot to overwritte so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the email change notification by using the 'send_email_change_email' hook.

Add this in your functions.php:

```
add_filter('send_email_change_email', '__return_false');
```